# How to modify windows policies from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, group-policy

I require to add some `gpedit.msc` policies, I require

- *"allow empty passwords not for only console"* in order to login easily via RDP without a password
- *"lock pages in memory"* for users "x" and "y"

What commands add such policies from command line, i would run this from .cm file

OS: Windows 10 x64, Windows 7 x64

Comment: Instead of modifying the group policy, you should be modifying, the associate registry key for that group policy.  What have you tried?  In either case you will need to be an Administrator user, and if you are on a domain, an Administrator on the domain itself.

Comment: I suggest using the [`Set-GPRegistryValue`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461034.aspx) PowerShell Cmdlet to acomplish your task

Comment: @Ramhound how could i figure out registry keys (and values) for desired policies? (2 subjects are in question)

Comment: The documentation for both group policies should provide that information